# Tkinter Dynamically updating text field with incoming messages

Tags: python, tkinter, bluetooth, ttk

so I am making a messaging app for a class and need to somehow use either a message field, or maybe scrolled text, in Tkinter to take in text message data. I have the data coming in over bluetooth so that isnt a concern, what I'm having trouble with (conceptually) is getting a message or scrolled text to dynamically update and display the recieved SMS message along with like a time stamp.

I had the idea of doing like a preformatted string that takes the content from the SMS as well as a time stamp and then just throwing that into the text field, but I have no clue if that would work.

Basically I would like to implement something like the log field in HTML when making chrome apps. A non editable field that simply displays text message data.
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: _"but I have no clue if that would work."_ - why not try it and see? Change or adding text to widgets is well documented, and there are many questions on this site related to updating widgets at runtime.

Comment: Where does this data go? To a textfile? Do you want to open it and read it to python?

Comment: @BryanOakley I'll definitely try it and see how it works out, I was just wondering if anyone knew of different ways to do what I mentioned.

Comment: @Uzzee The data is basically stored in a string once the background python code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the message in a string, this should work

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def updateDisplay(myString):
    displayVar.set(myString + ' --- ' + time.ctime())

root = Tk()

displayVar = StringVar()

displayLab = Label(root, textvariable=displayVar)

displayLab.pack()
```

call `updateDisplay(insertStringHere)` once you receive a message

Example

[image: testoutput]